# Change icon class on click for multiple cards using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, event-handling

I tried to change icon on click using a click listener and condition to change the class but I can't target one at click it affect all other cards,I want to know how I can target only one on click [the cards with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIef8.png)

```
//the click listener
status:boolean = false;
changeIcon(){
this.status = !this.status;
}
//the condition class changer
[ngClass]="status ? 'bi-heart-fill': 'bi-heart'
//button click
(click)="changeIcon()
```

Comment: If your button, your variable and your .html are in your component should be work. Generally this "oh! all the elements change" (that is something that all of us happens when start with Angular) happens when we use an unique variable to control a loop

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a card component with the required template.

Add an input to pass each card content to the card (ex. product).

Inside each card you can define a `status` property with same logic you mentioned.

And use a click listener to update the status for each card individually.

template.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of products">
   <!--Call card component here -->
   <card [product]="product"></card>
</ng-container>
```